# Socket won't release the memory

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, networking, network-programming

I have written a very simple socket that will send only 4 byte to a device in the network, it’s all works fine, however every time a new instant of the socket created, the memory will increase and it will stay like that whit out releasing the memory. The code I have written as follow:

```
    Byte[] bytesSent = new byte[4];
    bytesSent[0] = (byte)2;
    bytesSent[1] = (byte)1;
    bytesSent[2] = (byte)1;
    bytesSent[3] = (byte)1;

    Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,    ProtocolType.Tcp);
    sck.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAdd), 3152));
    sck.Send(bytesSent, SocketFlags.None);
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    sck.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    sck.Close();
    bytesSent = null;
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: Have you tried calling GC.Collect() to force garbage collection? Garbage collection won't otherwise occur unless the system is running out of physical memory or the heap has got too big.

Comment: yes i have, no difference ;(

Comment: Task Manager is not a memory profiler.  You will need to use a real one.

Comment: Have you considered keeping the socket open? Opening and closing a a socket just to send four bytes gives you a massive overhead in time and space on the wire.

Comment: Call Dispose() instead of/as well as Close(). Dispose is designed to released unmanaged resources such as the actual sockets that the Socket class acts as a wrapper for.

Answer (score 1):

C# uses a managed memory.  This means that there is a Garbage Collector that runs periodically and reclaims the memory that it can verify is no longer being used.  It won't clean everything up the instant it leaves scope; that is very expensive to try to do.  Instead it will wait until it's passed a set threshold for memory before it goes and does a sweep to look for things to clean up.  Because of this you'll see your program slowly increasing in memory over time, but then every once in a while it will drop down.  If that isn't happening, it means your program uses so little memory, or runs so quickly, that the GC hasn't even had a chance (or felt a need) to reclaim memory yet.  (Or it could mean that there is little to no memory that is *able* to be reclaimed in your program.)

Unless you get to the point where you program is taking up a huge amount of memory, or you start getting out of memory errors, you shouldn't concern yourself with this; just let the GC do its job.

Answer (score -1):

Class Sockets implements interface IDisposable, so it's preferable to use using statement i.e.

```
using(Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
{
sck.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAdd), 3152));
sck.Send(bytesSent, SocketFlags.None);
Thread.Sleep(10);
sck.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sck.Close();
bytesSent = null;
}
```

Comment: `Dispose` doesn't do much of anything but call `Close`, though.